# ONVIF video stream on camera side (not client side)

Tags: linux, gsoap, onvif

I am trying to write an ONVIF video stream at the camera side on Linux Fedora (not the client side).
I already installed the WSDL2H and ran:

> wsdl2h -c o onvif.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl

This command built the onvif.h

I wrote a UDP, HTTP, TCP server on my Linux.

In my UDP server program I catch the Hello message from the ONVIF Device Test Tool.
How should I proceed from this stage/point?
I would like to know how to write the "answer" function in C?

Answer (score 0):

At first you need soap tool like as [gsoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsoap2/).
Using gsoap you have to implement WS-Discovery 
(Hello message is the one of the WS-Discovery)

In the [gsoap FAQ](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapfaq.html), You can find useful information.
Also in the gsop documents, there is a information for [WS-Discovery](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.38.9)

Comment: Please, give me more details :
What I have is a Embeded camera system, with : 
an Image processing algo
an udp server
an HTTP server

so please what I need to do to add the gsoap to this 
"no head no tail" programme.

in fact the UDP server,HTTP server and ImageAlgo are 3 threads.
the ImageAlgo working with 15 image per sec...
the UDP Server listening on the port 3702 for incoming data.
on the HTTP server I have the Onvif Dir.

Now how can I add the gsoap functions to HTTP,UDP server?
Thanks